# azure application gateway behind azure front door multiple websites domains ssl

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer, azure-front-door

Infrastructure][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJSrs.png)

Info picture - all servers should have the same configurations and websites and ports.

The goal is that on all virtual servers in VMSS are running the different websites ( [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com) , [www.yyy.com](http://www.yyy.com) , wwww.zzz.com )
The SSL termination should be done at Front Door that is clear to me.

Questions: Where should i place the public ip? What should i configure that all websites are running and avaiable for users in application pool? I don't find a tutorial which describes my infrastructure. Could someone help me in this case?

Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Front Door is global load-balancing services which  distribute traffic from your end users across your regional backends.

Load Balancers and Application Gateways are regional load-balancing services which provide the ability to distribute traffic to virtual machines (VMs) within a virtual network (VNETs) or service endpoints within a region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-lb-with-azure-app-delivery-suite#choosing-a-global-load-balancer

Here is an example of Microsoft Azure DR architecture with Application Gateway, Front Door, Load Balancer and Traffic Manager.
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-lb-with-azure-app-delivery-suite

Considering your solution, you should configure SSL on FrontDoor and configure Application Gateway as backend.

Application Gateway should have VMSS configured as backend.

Comment: Hi i have done the steps, but i have the problem, that i have no chance to choice my Application Gateway during front-door setup. The field is empty , So what should i do. Could it be because Appliction getway is not configured completly?